# New Calendars created with API and Service account are not visible

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I am developing an  applicaiton using Google Calendar API v3 and Service account mode to have access. My application seems able to create new calendar without problem, but when I am going to check the result using Google Calendar standard web app I can't see nothing. This is strange because fetching  CalendarList return the proper calendar list.
Someone know why this happens? There is some limitation with calendar created with Service Account?

Thank you for your help.
Alberto

**UPDATE 1 :**

Here a snippet of my code

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_P12))
            // .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
            .build();

         Calendar service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

        com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar content = new com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar();
        content.setSummary("A calendar");
        service.calendars().insert(content).execute();
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

Someone suggest to me to add to credentials the service account user (then de-comment `.setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")` the code above, but it doesn't work. In this case I can't create neither a calendar and I receive when I call `service.calendars().insert(content).execute();` and I receive

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
```

Comment: you're right, sorry :)

Comment: Have you any idea? :(

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly obtain user's Calendar events using service account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210821/how-to-correctly-obtain-users-calendar-events-using-service-account)

Comment: I think you're missing Acl entry for the calendar created. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094240/who-owns-calendars-created-by-service-account-via-google-calendar-api-and-how-ca

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CalendarList.get()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get) function to confirm the Calendar is not `hidden=true` in the user's calendar list.

Comment: Hi Jay,  I tried your suggestion and printed the result 

service().calendarList().get(calendarId).execute().toPrettyString();

{
  "accessRole" : "owner",
  "backgroundColor" : "#fa573c",
  "colorId" : "4",
  "etag" : "\"HvdNzJLFsPN6WzLOxlO1URKnJIE/ji0r5Uh3FsdbdNcKGxyRG7OA8n8\"",
  "foregroundColor" : "#000000",
  "id" : "mo012ecmkf3mrqmp5hjctj630s@group.calendar.google.com",
  "kind" : "calendar#calendarListEntry",
  "selected" : true,
  "summary" : "deviceId",
  "timeZone" : "UTC"
}

Maybe because I newb with G API but I can't retrieve 'hidden' value

Comment: I delve into the api, the hidden value is null then CalendarListEntry#isHidden method return false :-\

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an incomplete GoogleCredential. Try with ClientSecrets and refresh token.

```
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
    GoogleCredential credential = new  GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
    .setJsonFactory( new JacksonFactory())
    .setServiceAccountId("id@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("privatekey.p12"))
    .setClientSecrets("clientID", "clientSecret")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
    .build();
    credential.refreshToken();
```

Regards

Comment: Where do you get those values: `clientID`, `clientSecret`? Besides, the Java client seems to have all the credentials it needs to create calendars, so how could it be that its credentials are incomplete?