# How to public secondary google calendar using Google Calendar API and Service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am having similar issues as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094240/who-owns-calendars-created-by-service-account-via-google-calendar-api-and-how-ca/31869857?noredirect=1#comment51658361_31869857). My application is able to create a new calendar, with its  calendarId `qtg79cn1gs9ci7uge98is7pv6k@group.calendar.google.com`.

However, I can't see anything in the Google Calendar web app (logged in with service account).  I know that I have created a secondary calendar. How can I add it as an entry to the user's calendar list ?

Comment: Can you please describe your use case clearly? Do you want to see calendar created by service account in calendars list?

Comment: Please add the clarification in the question, instead of the comments.  thanks.