# Google Calendar API: service account shared calendar issue

Tags: google-calendar-api

My scenario:

Created a Service account for google calendar - say MasterAccount. 
Have another SlaveAccount and shared the calendar via (Shared: Edit settings) with MasterAccount.

I am getting access denied error when I use ServiceAccount to access SlaveAccount shared calendar.

```
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
```

How can I use service account to access another account?

Comment: If you want to access user data for users in your Google Apps domain, then [delegate domain-wide access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) to the service account. To delegate domain-wide authority to a service account, enable domain-wide delegation for an existing service account in the [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts) or [create a new service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) with domain-wide delegation enabled.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094240/who-owns-calendars-created-by-service-account-via-google-calendar-api-and-how-ca

Comment: Henry, did you find a solution for or different approach to this scenario?  We are faced with exactly the same task - accessing Google Calendar accounts that have been shared with a Service Account.  We are just now starting on a POC, so haven't run into your "access denied" issue, but would like to have a solution if/when it comes up.  Many thanks!