# Google Calendar service account and shared resource calendars (e.g. rooms): freebusy acces only

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I am trying to get events for a shared resource calendar (a meeting room) via a service account. I added service account email to the list of access like this:

[image]

But when I make a call via Google Calendar API to get a list of events for that calendar, all events are marked "private" and thus I can only get free / busy information for that calendar.

But when I did the same for a 'normal' user calendar, not a resource calendar, it works perfectly well. The problem occurs only with resource calendars.

I guess there should be some setting in G Suite Console that sets access levels for resource calendars, but I just don't know where it is?

I've found this question here: [Who owns calendars created by service account via Google Calendar API and how can they be shared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094240/who-owns-calendars-created-by-service-account-via-google-calendar-api-and-how-ca#21097488) but it is about calendars created by service accounts which is not my case.

Comment: So, you  are trying to access to the same event but from different calendars (resource and user) using the service account credentials,  for the user calendar you get the information but for the resource you doesn't?

Comment: @jds1993 yes, that's the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case and as you said, in the Google Admin console you can set up resource permissions in:

Apps > G Suite > Calendar > General settings >  Resource booking permissions

Source
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6262207